# LinqToEntities Grouping

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-entities

I have a message list having members:

> Text = m.Text, User = m.User, Date = m.Date

This list include all the messages like

```
Text = "How Are You"
User = "Michael"
Date = "1/1/12"

Text = "Well Done"
User = "Michael"
Date = "2/1/12"

Text = "Who?"
User = "John"
Date = "1/1/12"
```

I kindly require to get the newest messages from the people which won't show multiple messages from the same person and give only the last one like:

```
Text = "Well Done"
User = "Michael"
Date = "2/1/12"

Text = "Who?"
User = "John"
Date = "1/1/12"
```

As you see; I want to eliminate the previous message from the same person.

I am currently using:

```
var messages = (from m in mList select new
{
Text = m.Text, 
User = m.User, 
Date = m.Date
}).ToList();
```

What should I add to this query to achieve my goal?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var messages = (from m in mList select new
{
   Text = m.Text, 
   User = m.User, 
   Date = m.Date
})
.GroupBy(m => m.User)
.Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(m => m.Date).First())
.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks David! That was so easy :)

Comment: @MrGorki: as TheHe points out, the `OrderBy` here would assume an actual date rather than a date string. I would advise that you parse it to a date. If you don't like the idea of parsing, but know that you can rely on the list to be in chronological order, you may use `.Last()` instead to just pick whichever entry is last in the list, for each individual user.

Comment: The only distortion was .First() but it worked with .FirstOrDefault() without any problem.. Great! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
    var messages = (from m in mList select new
    {
        Text = m.Text, 
        User = m.User, 
        Date = DateTime.Parse(m.Date)
    })
    .GroupBy(x => x.User).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
}catch{}
```

because the date is not string-sortable...